# Does onClick() pass as a props by default in React Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two component. CourseInput.js and Button.js. In the CourseInput.js component I create a React form and inside that form I use Button component. I pass type as a props only. But in the Button.js component how I can access onClick function though I haven't pass it in Button.js component. How Button.js component is getting onClick function as props in onClick= {props.onClick}.

**CourseInput.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import "./CourseInput.css";

const CourseInput = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState("");

  const goalInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onAddGoal(enteredValue);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className="form-control">
        <label>Course Goal</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={goalInputChangeHandler} />
      </div>
      <Button type="submit">Add Goal</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CourseInput;
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from "react";

import "./Button.css";

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button type={props.type} className="button" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

*My code is working as expected but how this props.onClick works? *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onClick is undefined for the button and since its JS, it won't complain, even if you remove it, the code will work. When you type the button as submit, it will just invoke the onSubmit function on the form.

Comment: And how this button can invoke onSubmit function in Parent Component CourseInput.js ?

Comment: @SamiulKarim button with type 'submit' will look for a parent form handler. it was commonly used before JS became popular for form controls. Back in the old days it was common for forms to sends whatever it contains to an endpoint via form-data without JS. 
Ex: https://www.dofactory.com/html/button/submit